# How to create a RadioButtonList where each radio button is in a separate table row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I'm creating an MCQ Question and answer Interface where I need to place my each radio option in separete row next to the answer, so that user can select the answer, I know to use radiobutton list in a single row in normal way,

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="opt_questiontype" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnClick="call()">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="MCQ" Selected="True">MCQ</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Single">Single Answer</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

but here i need to place them in row by row in an html table as follows,

```
<table id="mcqtable">
        <tr style="border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#CCCCCC;">
            <th class="captions2">Option</th><th class="captions2">Answer Text</th><th class="captions2">Is Correct</th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
                <td class="captions1">Answer Option 1</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_answeropt1" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox></td><td><asp:RadioButton ID="opt_answer1" runat="server" GroupName="grp_answers" Checked="true" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions1">Answer Option 2</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_answeropt2" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox></td><td><asp:RadioButton ID="opt_answer2" runat="server" GroupName="grp_answers" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions1">Answer Option 3</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_answeropt3" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox></td><td><asp:RadioButton ID="opt_answer3" runat="server" GroupName="grp_answers" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions1">Answer Option 4</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_answeropt4" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox></td><td><asp:RadioButton ID="opt_answer4" runat="server" GroupName="grp_answers" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Here I have used normal radiobuttons, but there is a conflict when getting the selected value, So please any one could suggest a way to use **asp:RadioButtonList** to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

> here I have used normal radiobuttons, but there is a conflict when
>   getting the selected value

What is conflict? why you want to use RAdioButtonList here? Your existing code does not show me any conflict.

Comment: From which attribute I am gonna call the selected value? cannot call from GroupName right? also each radio have separate ID..

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. You want to fire an event whenever user select Radio button against question?

Comment: The event will not fire on selection, but the selected option value should be posted when i click a button, so I can use the value from code behind, event will fire on click of the button

Comment: Well you can do this by assigning different GroupNames to each Radio button. Currently u have assigned same Group Name. And if you are want to use RadioButton List then use as:::::: <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >  
                     <asp:ListItem Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:RadioButtonList> .......... Now when you will press button u can access each value.

Answer (score 0):

You should set [`RepeatDirection="Vertical"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatdirection.aspx) in order to show the options row-wise.

Please refer my answer @CodeProject - [Change ASP radiobuttonlist repeatdirection property with Javascript or JQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/602625/ChangeplusASPplusradiobuttonlistplusrepeatdirectio#answer2) for a more detailed information on how we can toggle between Vertical and Horizontal alignments.

Demo - [[Demo] Change Repeat Direction of asp RadioButtonList](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/v4NAk/)

**EDIT**

Do like below...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="opt_questiontype" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Vertical" OnClick="call()">
```

Comment: You have used html radio buttons right? In my case i need asp:RadioButtonList, please can u tell me how can i apply it on the above case..

Comment: Actually in that answer link I just referred to the rendered html of asp RadiobuttonList, not html RadioButtons....

I just mean to say that do like below...

`<asp:RadioButtonList ID="opt_questiontype" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Vertical" OnClick="call()">`

Answer (score 0):

Either use repeater or you can use css to create single row for each radio button.

In repeater you can control the HTML as per your requirement